# How do I change the value of any global variable inside of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript. I want to have a function that can change the value of a given global variable. My code has to have the following structure:

```
function change(variable_name, new_value){
    //Code to make it work!
}
```

and I want the function to work like this:

```
var x = 0;
change(x,2);
```

and at this point the variable x should be equal to 2.

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: What you are asking for can't be done. Not in the way you are asking for it. This will ONLY work for arrays and objects, as they are pass-by-reference, but primitives are pass-by-value, so you can't just modify them like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the variable name as a string

```
function change(variable_name, new_value){
    window[variable_name] = new_value
}

var x = 0;
change('x',2); //  pass the variable name as a string, instead of the variable
```